# Make voice sound smoother

Tags: microphone, voice, voice-over

I need to create a narration audio, my voice doesn't sound good and I want to make it sound smoother. For example the [Yes Theory](https://www.youtube.com/user/PracProcrastination) youtube channel when they do a type vlog video their voice sound normal and a bit rough, but when they start doing the narration during the beginning and at the end of the video their voice sounds better and smoother. How do I come up with something similar? **can I edit the voice** or is it just the **good mic condenser**.

Answer (score 2):

Its a combination of a lot of things but mostly mic, position and performance are key. There are some things you can do in post but without the key ingredients you are limited. Post production is essentially glitter-rolling. Recording and performance are about making sure its not a turd you are rolling in glitter.